# Why isn't Rostest running my gtests in catkin?

Tags: ros, catkin, rostest, gtest, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run a rostest that subscribes to topics of the node it tests.  It is made with gtests.  Currently, I'm trying to make the rostest deliberately fail using assert_true(false), etc.

However, no matter what I do, running `rostest my_package CLASStester.test` returns success with absolutely no information.  I've checked the xml log files and there's also no trace of test information (also, I can never seem to get "cout" statements in the CLASStester.cpp file to print anything in the terminal).

The following shows...roughly...what I believe are the relevant sections from my CMakeLists.txt.

```
add_library(CLASSForTesting src/CLASS.cpp include/mypackage/CLASS.h)

target_link_libraries(CLASS ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

catkin_add_gtest(CLASSTester include/mypackage/test/CLASSTester.h src/test/CLASSTester.cpp include/mypackage/CLASS.h include/mypackage/CLASS.h)

target_link_libraries(CLASSTester ${catkin_LIBRARIES} CLASSForTesting)

set_target_properties(CLASSTester PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME CLASSTester)

add_rostest(test/CLASSTester.test)

add_dependencies(CLASSTester ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencpp)
```

There doesn't seem to be much documentation on using rostest with catkin.  Let me know if there's anything else you need.  Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69475/why-isn%27t-rostest-running-my-gtests-in-catkin?/) by [Toletum](https://answers.ros.org/users/5178/toletum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2013-07-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-07-29**:
First you need to decide if your test is actually a GTest or a rostest. You registered both which is very likely wrong. For a more detailed answer please provide more information about your files (e.g. a repo containing the code in question).

**Comment by [Toletum](https://answers.ros.org/users/5178/toletum/) on 2013-07-29**:
Are gtests still intended to be used with rostests?  Otherwise, what IS the point of rostest?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-07-29**:
A GTest tends to be a standalone executable which does unit testing (tests individual functions in the component being tested). rostest allows you to do integration testing, by setting up a launch file which starts a roscore, and potentially several nodes and asserts things about the ROS interface of those nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this related question](http://answers.ros.org/question/54075/how-does-rostest-work-with-catkin/).

The catkin documentation [is here](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/howto/index.html#configuring-unit-tests). It does not directly address the combination of gtest and rostest.

The [camera_info_manager](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/tree/groovy-devel/camera_info_manager) tests do something similar. You can compare that package.xml and CMakeLists.txt to yours.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2